# Subset geopandas dataframe return nonetype

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, shapely

I have a few geodataframes with geometry type linestring and point and I'd like to subset each gdf into 2 based on geometry type. I used below code to subset it:

```
gdf1_line = gdf1[gdf1['geometry'].geom_type == 'LineString']
gdf1_point = gdf1[gdf1['geometry'].geom_type == 'Point']
```

Since I have multiple gdf, I try to make a function like this:

```
def subset_line(x):
    result =  x[x['geometry'].geom_type == 'LineString']
    return result

def subset_point(x):
    result =  x[x['geometry'].geom_type == 'Point']
    return result
```

However, when I try to run it showed this error:

```
gdf_line = subset_line(gdf)

gdf_line.head()
```

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Apparently, i have to create the gdf in the function like this:

```
def subset_line(x):
    result =  pd.DataFrame(x[x['geometry'].geom_type == 'LineString'])
    return result
```

Comment: This returns a pandas dataframe, not a geodataframe. There’s no way the original code returned a None - you must have had a different error. Please make sure your code is reproducible, ideally as a [mre], and always post the full traceback when asking about errors